# Треугольник адаптивно?

Tags: css, вёрстка, svg, адаптивная-верстка

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать блок с текстом как на картинке, чтобы если текст расширяет блок триугольник растягивался вместе с блоком.
[image: Стрелка)]

Comment: тр**и**угольник...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариант с `clip-path`

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.triangle{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    max-width: 250px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 30px;
    background: #333;
    color: #ccc;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(10% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 10% 100%, 0 50%);
clip-path: polygon(10% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 10% 100%, 0 50%);
-webkit-clip-path: url("#clip-triangle");
    clip-path: url("#clip-triangle");
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle">text</div>
<div class="triangle">text text text text text text text text text text text text</div>
<div class="triangle">Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать блок с текстом как на картинке, чтобы если текст расширяет блок триугольник растягивался вместе с блоком.</div>

<svg width="0" height="0">
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="clip-triangle" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
            <polygon points="0.1 0, 1 0, 1 1, 0.1 1, 0 0.5" />
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: А подскажите пожалуйста кроссбраузерность данного метода и возможно по svg уроки толковые можете посоветовать? Вы в ручную пишете полигон или экспортируете из редакторов? Спасибо за ответ очень полезен.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант можно сделать так :)

```css
.dd {
  min-height: 20px;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  margin: 10px ;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 15px;
  z-index: 9;
  color: #fff;
}
.dd> p {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9;
}
.dd:before {
      position:absolute;
      height: 0;
      top: 50%;
      max-width: 300%;
      border-right: 500px solid #3aa5de;
      border-bottom: 1000px solid transparent;
      content: "";
      left: 90%;
      border-radius:0;
      margin-left: 10px;
      transform: scaleX(-1) translateX(100%);
}

.dd:after {
      position:absolute;
      height: 0;
      top: 50%;
      transform:scaleY(-1) scaleX(-1) translateY(100%)     translateX(100%);
      max-width: 300%;
      border-radius:0;
      border-right: 500px solid #3aa5de;
      border-bottom: 1000px solid transparent;
      content: "";
      left: 90%;
      margin-left: 10px;
}

.ddd {
  min-height: 20px;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 10px ;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 15px 0 30px;
  z-index: 9;
  color: #fff;
}
.ddd> p {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9;
}
.ddd:before {
  position:absolute;
  height: 0;
  top: 50%;
  max-width: 100%;
  border-left: 500px solid #3aa5de;
  border-bottom: 1000px solid transparent;
  content: "";
  left: 0%;
  border-radius:0;
  //margin-left: 10px;
  transform: scaleX(-1) translateX(0%);
}

.ddd:after {
  position:absolute;
  height: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform:scaleY(-1) scaleX(-1) translateY(100%)     translateX(0%);
  max-width: 100%;
  border-radius:0;
  border-left: 500px solid #3aa5de;
  border-bottom: 1000px solid transparent;
  content: "";
  left: 0%;
  //margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dd"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p></div>
<div class="dd"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora, id.</p></div>
<div class="ddd"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p></div>
<div class="ddd"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora, id.</p></div>
```

Comment: Интересный метод, спасибо.