# Стрелка при наведении

Tags: css, hover

Здравствуйте? Каким методом реализуется подобное? При наведении должна появляться стрелка в виде треугольника как на скриншоте?[image: скриншот макета]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Треугольник адаптивно?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/669555/%d0%a2%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba-%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be)

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант:

```css
body{
  text-align: center;
}

div{
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu-item{
  position: relative;
  height: 120px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 90%, 60% 90%, 40% 90%, 0 90%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 90%, 60% 90%, 40% 90%, 0 90%);
}

.menu-item:first-child{
  background: rgba(169,3,41,1);
}

.menu-item:nth-child(2){
  background: rgba(0,123,247,1);
}

.menu-item:last-child{
  background: rgba(117,168,0,1);
}

.menu-item:hover{
  display:inline-block;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 90%, 60% 90%, 51% 100%, 40% 90%, 0 90%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 90%, 60% 90%, 51% 100%, 40% 90%, 0 90%);  
}

.menu-item:first-child:hover{
  background: rgb(109,0,25);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(109,0,25,1) 0%,rgba(143,2,34,1) 31%,rgba(169,3,41,1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(109,0,25,1) 0%,rgba(143,2,34,1) 31%,rgba(169,3,41,1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(109,0,25,1) 0%,rgba(143,2,34,1) 31%,rgba(169,3,41,1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#6d0019', endColorstr='#a90329',GradientType=1 );
}

.menu-item:nth-child(2):hover{
  background: rgb(0,60,107);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(0,60,107,1) 0%,rgba(3,98,170,1) 30%,rgba(0,123,247,1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(0,60,107,1) 0%,rgba(3,98,170,1) 30%,rgba(0,123,247,1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(0,60,107,1) 0%,rgba(3,98,170,1) 30%,rgba(0,123,247,1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#003c6b', endColorstr='#007bf7',GradientType=1 );
}

.menu-item:last-child:hover{
  background: rgb(39,66,0);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(39,66,0,1) 0%, rgba(66,140,2,1) 38%, rgba(117,168,0,1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(39,66,0,1) 0%,rgba(66,140,2,1) 38%,rgba(117,168,0,1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(39,66,0,1) 0%,rgba(66,140,2,1) 38%,rgba(117,168,0,1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#274200', endColorstr='#75a800',GradientType=1 );
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-wrapper">
  <div class="menu-item"></div>
  <div class="menu-item"></div>
  <div class="menu-item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, подскажите ещё пожалуйста как сделать такую внутреннюю  тень?  чтобы  она  падала на  блок  и на  стрелку

Comment: @Daniel Deffo MortanPlay поправил ответ. Долго игрался с тенью треугольнику. Так чтобы выглядело правдоподобно. Вариант, что предоставил выше - меньше кода, выглядит лучше. Но кроссбраузерность пострадала.  Хром, Опера, Мозила - норм. Про IE забудьте. Safari под вопросом.

Comment: С градиентом можете поиграться тут - http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/